# Storing observable data into global variable returns 'undefined' in Angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular

I am currently working with a node server that I've set up and created an endpoint `/user-info` which `res.send({id: <my-id>, name: <my-display-name>})`

On Angular I have created a `global.service.ts` file that will call this endpoint using `http.get` and subscribe that data and store into two variables I have declared.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class Globals {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public id: string;
    public name: string;

    userInfo() {
        this.http.get('/user-info').subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
                this.id = data.id;                    
            }
        );
        console.log(this.id);
    }

}
```

Once I `console.log(this.id)` it returns `undefined`. I have already the server-side to see if that was causing the problem but it returns a string.

In my `server.js` file (node server) I am working with express. This is the endpoint:

```
app.get('/user-info', function(req, res) {
    client.get('id', (err, data) => {
        client.get('name', (err, reply) => {
            res.send({id: data, name: reply})
        })
    })
})
```

I am using redis to store values `'id'` and `'name'` and the `client.get` is just a redis command used to call those values from cache. I have tested just checking `localhost:8000/user-info` and everything looks fine.

Am I missing/misunderstanding something? Thanks!

Comment: How does your response look? And also your `console.log(this.id))` should go inside `subscribe` block. This is an asynchronous task.

Comment: @AmitChigadani I have updated the question to show the server-side code and also put the console.log inside the subscribe function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if console.log still outside of call, it will execute before you got a response. Try this:

```
userInfo() {
        this.http.get('/user-info').subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
                this.id = data.id
                console.log(this.id);
            }
        )

    }
```

Comment: You'r wellcome!